# why does shell use executable in /usr/bin and not in /usr/local/bin

Tags: bash

Given:

```
/usr/local/bin/cmake
/usr/bin/cmake
$ cmake # runs /usr/bin/cmake

$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

Why this, and how do I make the shell run the executable `/usr/local/bin/cmake` when I type `cmake` (without aliases and the like)?

Comment: Related: [Why not use "which"? What to use then?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/85249)

Comment: If that is your path, the cmake in /usr/local/bin should take precedence. What is the output of `which cmake` and `type -a cmake`?

Comment: `which` points to `/usr/local/bin/cmake`; `type -a` returns two lines, one for each. `type -f` returns: `cmake is hashed (/usr/bin/cmake)`

Comment: okay, I cleared the bash hash, the problem went away

Comment: @Kusalananda Please try to avoid recommending `which` since this is software designed for  `csh` from 1979 that does not work well together with shells similar to the Bourne Shell. Rather use `type`, as this is built into the shell and knows how your current shell will decide.

Comment: @schily I don't think I ever have recommended `which`.  If I did, let me know where and I'll correct it.

Comment: Well, the problem is the title of the article that you copied without comment in your comment. It at the first glance looks as if you recommend `which`.

Comment: @schily That's a canonical question relating to the _issues_ with `which`.

Comment: This has been asked before.  For examples see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/91173/5132 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/39817/5132 .

Comment: @schily An early version of this question featured references to the output of `which`, hence the link could have been relevant.

Comment: @JdeBP Agree fully, can be closed as  duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was revealed by running

```
$ type -f cmake
cmake is hashed (/usr/bin/cmake)
```

And clearing the bash hash with

```
hash -d cmake
```

After this, `cmake` was interpreted as expected.

Answer (score 3):

At some earlier point during the same shell session, you have used `cmake` and that executable was found in `/usr/bin`.

You then installed another `cmake` executable in `/usr/local/bin`.

The `bash` shell caches the first location that it finds for any external command that you use, which means it doesn't have to do an expensive search for the executable the next time you use the same command.  The downside of this is that it won't bother to look *again* when you, later, install another executable by the same name, even if it's done in a directory that occurs earlier in `$PATH` than the original location.

The solution to this issue is to empty the cached locations of executables that `bash` keeps.  This is done with `hash -r` (`rehash` in the `zsh` shell).  To only forget the location of the `cmake` executable, use `hash -d cmake` (`unhash cmake` in the `zsh` shell).

---

An earlier version of this question additionally wondered why the two commands `type cmake` and `which cmake` gave different results, where `which cmake` appeared to give the expected result (`/usr/local/bin/cmake`) while `type cmake` appeared to give the wrong result (`/usr/bin/cmake`).

The answer to that is that `type` is a built-in command in `bash` that will use the same cached locations of commands that the shell uses, and that `which` is *not* a built-in command and will therefore not be able to use those cached locations of executables.

In this case, `which` gave the expected result because it did a search for `cmake` in your `$PATH`, but it was in fact the *wrong* result, since running `cmake` on the command line would in fact *not* pick it up from `/usr/local/bin` (due to the caching, which `which` would be unaware of).

A summary of the history of `which`, and the pitfalls of using it, is found here: [Why not use "which"? What to use then?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85249)